# Alternating series using Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, sum

I am trying to use Haskell to read in a list and perform an alternating series, so starting with the first element adding every other and subtracting every other from the second element.  For instance [1, 2, 3, 4] would be 1-2+3-4=-2. I thought I had figured out how to do this for lists of a specific length (I wrote it to accommodate empty lists and lists up to 4 elements long), but it doesn't do what I thought it would.  It just returns the first element from the list. Here is what I have:

```
altSeries :: Num a => [a] -> a
altSeries [] = 0
altSeries (x:xs) = if length xs == 1 then x
                   else if length xs == 2 then x
                   else if length xs == 3 then (x - xs!!1 + xs!!2)
                   else (x - xs!!1 + xs!!2 - xs!!3)
```

Also, what if I wanted to be able to use any list size?

Comment: I don't know how you tested your code, but it doesn't even handle lists of length 1.

Comment: For most exercises, you should forget `length,head,tail,!!` exist, and go purely using pattern matching and recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is clear that this solution **does not scale**: even if you would write up function up to lists with length thousand, it would break from the moment that someone enters a list with thousand and one elements.

List processing usually is done **recursively**: we process the *head* (or the first *k* heads) of a list, and perform recursion on the tail of the list. Furthermore we have a number of *basecases* (can be one) to terminate recursion.

You already provided a single base case: the empty list:

```
altSeries [] = 0
```

In case we enter an empty list, it is clear that we should return `0`. Now we might ask what to do in case we obtain a list of length 1: in that case the list has shape `[x]`. So in that case we should return `x`, since we should add `x`, and can not subtract the second number. So we add:

```
altSeries [x] = x
```

Now the question is what to do with lists with length two or more. In that case the list has pattern `(x1:x2:t)` with `x1` the first element, `x2` the second element, and `t` the remaining elements. Based on your description we should caculate `x1-x2` and add `altSeries t`:

```
altSeries (x1:x2:t) = x1 - x2 + altSeries t
```

This works since `altSeries` will then recursively extract `x3` and `x4`, so then it will recurse to:

```
altSeries [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] = x1 - x2 + altSeries [x3,x4,x5]
                           = x1 - x2 + x3 - x4 + altSeries [x5]
                           = x1 - x2 + x3 - x4 + x5
```

So the full implementation is:

```
altSeries :: Num n => [n] -> n
altSeries [] = 0
altSeries [x] = x
altSeries (x1:x2:t) = x1 - x2 + altSeries t
```

Comment: Could be simplified to `altSeries xs = sum (zipWith (*) (cycle [1, -1]) xs)` or `altSeries = sum . zipWith id (cycle [id, negate])`.

Comment: Nice anser on good level of complexity.  Doesn't need to be more complicated or abstract than that. :)

Comment: @melpomene: Although this evidently works, it introduces a lot of higher level functions and other magic. Based on the question, I don't think this will improve the level of the OP. But feel free to add an answer :) I will upvote it.

Comment: These solutions, while correct, are unnecessarily complex.  Try this:

`altSeries (x:xs) = x - altSeries xs`
`altSeries _       = 0`

This is not only simpler, but almost certainly faster.  Of course, if you want high performance, you'll want to make this function strict:

Comment: @CarlEdman Strictness will make no difference to the speed of that function. In fact any increase in strictness over what you have there will slow it down. If you want better performance you will want a tail recursive function, so `altSeries = go 0 1 where go t _ [] = t; go t m (x : xs) = go (t + m * x) (negate m) xs`, now then you would want strictness in the numeric arguments, although GHC can hopefully figure that out for you.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a list that ultimately looks something like this `[1,-2,3,-4]` which you could sum.

You can make a list of alternating sign `[1,-1]`. this can be made infinite using the [cycle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) function. `let alternatingSigns = cycle [1,-1]`

To transform a list of `[1,2,3,4]` you can zip the infinite alternating list with your list like this `zipWith (*) alternatingSigns input`

The whole function would look something like this:

```
altSeries :: Num a => [a] -> a
altSeries input = let alternatingSigns = cycle [1,-1]
                  in sum $ zipWith (*) alternatingSigns input
```

Comment: While we are at it, why not do away with the multiplication? `altSum = either id id . foldl (\e n -> either (Right . (+ n)) (Left . (subtract n)) e) (Left 0)`.   :)

Comment: @Alec `foldr (-) 0` seems simpler (if you aren't trying to make it strict).

Comment: @DavidFletcher I was just playing around - my comment wasn't intended to be serious. Although yes, this would be better with `foldl'`.

Comment: I upvoter this and I like the foldl but Haskell is declarative so 
`altl ls = [ if even n then (-n) else n | n <- ls]`